# Windows sensors API - getting sensors events

Tags: c++, windows, api, sensors

I'm trying to get events from a sensor in windows with the "SetEventSink" function of ISensor, (c++). but I get no events! (i have the sensor and i can get data from it with the "GetData" function of ISensor).

I followed the instructions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319014(v=vs.85).aspx

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but... when you call CoInitialize to initialize COM, you have to call the CoInitializeEx version instead and pass in the multi-threaded flag. This will allow you to receive asynchronous events from the sensors.

```
CoInitializeEx(COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```